# In which module should I declare Angular Directive?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-module

I have a Directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[ICheck]',
})
export class ICheckDirective {

    @Input()
    ICheck: string;

    constructor(element: ElementRef) {
        var $element: any = $(element.nativeElement);

        $element.iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_md',
            radioClass: 'iradio_md',
            increaseArea: '20%'
        })
    }

}
```

Where I declare it in `app.module`

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
        ICheckDirective,
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I got an error in my component `RoleListComponent` in `roles.module`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RoleListComponent,
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
    ]
})
export class RolesModule { }
```

Error I got

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'ICheck' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. (" 
>   
>                                   ][ICheck] />

my routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: DashboardComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'users',
                loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'roles',
                loadChildren: './roles/roles.module#RolesModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'portalpageowners',
                loadChildren: './portalpageowner/portalpageowner.module#PortalPageOwnerModule'
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add into declarations of that module in which you want to use it. In your case into the `RoleModule`. But if you need to add it into more modules, you need to create a `SharedModule`, export that directive from it

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [ ..., ICheckDirective, ... ],
   exports: [ ..., ICheckDirective, ... ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

and import this module into another modules.

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [ ..., SharedModule, ... ]
})
export class RoleModule { }

...

@NgModule({
   imports: [ ..., SharedModule, ... ]
})
export class AnotherModule { }
```

`export` will make the directive visible to the declarations of those modules which import `SharedModule`.